# How can I build a fat jar from a published manifest?

Tags: java, maven

I have a deployment process where gradle publishes a set of jar files for some microservices.  This generates artifacts in the repository that look something like the following:

```
pkg     service-1.0.0.jar
javadoc service-1.0.0-javadoc.jar
pom     service-1.0.0.pom
sources service-1.0.0-sources.jar
```

This is great if someone wants to use service-1.0.0.jar in their own project that goes out and fetches all the dependencies and such.  I'm now trying to build a Docker image off of this though.  Something as simple as `java -jar service-1.0.0.jar`.

Problem is that jar isn't a shaded jar - there's a bunch of dependencies it's missing.  Is there a decent way to pull in all the dependency the jar needs to run?

I started with this:

```
curl -u "..." "https://...service-1.0.0.pom" > pom.xml
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This seems promising, but it hits a snag where it tries to download a dependency from a private repository (technically the same one the pom comes from).

I don't really want to get into hacking the pom file to inject a `distributionManagement` section or something like that.  Is there a clever way around this?  Some way on the command line to tell maven to search a private repository if it can't find something in Maven central?

Or is there a generally better way to handle this (without publishing the original as a fat jar - I'd like to avoid that)?

Comment: Do you want to create an executable fat jar using maven ? Then, I have solution for this.

Comment: No - I don't want to change the published jar.

Comment: Can you explain in short ? What is your objective so that I can provide the exact solution if I know ?

Comment: Also add the pom.xml for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need to add your private repository (or list of them) to your `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` (both on `Linux` or `windows`) - (more on [guide multiple repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html))

When having multiple repositories configured, maven will search in all the repositories, including the private ones. In this case, no need to modify your `pom.xml`. The drawback is that you'll see for each `.jar` pulled the query to all these repositories.

If you're in company with access to Apache Archiva / Nexus / Artifactory, you can configure a group of repository, and this group will consist of all the public and private ones, and then your `maven` configuration will look only in 1 location that will also cache all these packages.

Comment: I think this is basically right, but I also think it requires hacking the pom.xml.  Somehow I think you need to get the `<repositories>` section into the pom - it won't indiscriminately search every repo in your settings.  I was hoping there was some maven flag or setting that would tell it "yes - go ahead and search these repos if Maven central fails".

Comment: Interesting - maybe my comment is wrong...  from that link looks like you can set the url in the settings.xml.  Let me try that

Comment: This is the answer I needed.  To dereference the URL in the answer, the settings.xml can contain a profile <profiles><profile><id>...</id><repositories><repository><id>...</id><url>...</url></repository></repositories></profile></profiles> - that will let you customize what repositories are searched for artifacts without any modification of the original POM.  I also put Maven Central in there first to make sure it checks there first and doesn't proxy everything through my private repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

Once you apply the shadow plugin, the shadowJar task will be available. This should create a jar with all the dependencies in the lib/ folder inside of the jar.

Comment: I don't want to change the gradle process that publishes the skinny jar.  I want to take the jar and accompanying POM file and download everything it needs.  The problem is that POM manifest points at artifacts in private repositories - how do I resolve those?